# Using routing info outside of the React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-router, es6-modules

I am using a fetch function that is extracted outside so that it can be used across the entire application. I am calling this wrapper function whenever I want to make any API requests. But the problem here is , I need to handle a case whenever server returns a 401,100 or any status code I basically want to redirect to login page. But I would not be having the routing info here , Any idea how could this be solved?

this function looks something like this:

```
export module FetchWrapper {
  export async function fetchCall(url, type, headers) {
    let url = obj.url;
    let options = {};
    options.method = type;
    options.headers = { ...options.headers, ...headers };
    const response = await fetch(url, options);
    return await response.json();
  }
}
```

### Any Component would use like this:

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      let response = await FetchWrapper.fetchCall({
        url: `/api/fetch/details`,
        type: "GET",
        headers: { contentType: "application/json" } 
      });
     //on success
    } catch (error) {
      // error handling
    }
  }
```

### Routing defintion inside App.tsx

```
<Switch>
     <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Start} />
     <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
     <Route path="/signout" component={SignOut} />
     <Route path="/page1" component={Page1} />
     <Route path="/page2" component={Page2} />
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export module FetchWrapper {
    export async function fetchCall(history, {url, type, headers}) {
        let url = obj.url;
        let options: any = {};
        options.method = type;
        options.headers = { ...options.headers, ...headers };

        const response = await fetch(url, options);
        if (response.status === 401 || response.status === 100) {
            history.replace("/login");
            // you can throw error and catch when execute or what you want
        } else {
            return await response.json();
        }
    }
}




async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      let response = await FetchWrapper.fetchCall(history,{
        url: `/api/fetch/details`,
        type: "GET",
        headers: { contentType: "application/json" } 
      });
     //on success
    } catch (error) {
      // error handling
    }
  }
```

check both function again

i hope it works

Comment: you will get it as props in the component

Comment: can componentDidmount access history ?

Comment: @Man yes it does. If I try using this.props.history and wrap the component with withRouter

Comment: i guess you are using v3 route thats why it possible

Answer (score 0):

Using "history" from "react-router-dom" pretty much solved it.

### Inside the index file

```
    import { Router } from "react-router-dom";
    import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
    export const history = createBrowserHistory();
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Router history={history}>
          <App />
      </Router>,
      document.getElementById("root")
    );
```

And in the wrapper file using it like this

```
import { history } from "../../index";
export module FetchWrapper {
    export async function fetchCall(url, type, headers) {
        let url = obj.url;
        let options: any = {};
        options.method = type;
        options.headers = { ...options.headers, ...headers };
        const response = await fetch(url, options);
        if (response.status === 401 || response.status === 100) {
            history.replace("/login");
        } else {
            return await response.json();
        }
    }
}
```